# Spring Batch: Single job instance listener

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I want to make sure that only one job instance is allowed to run. and if another instance is already running then stop it.
So i implemented a listener that checks the number of running Jobs like below: (i'm not sur if it's the correct impl to stop the jobs)

```
public class SingleJobInstanceListener implements JobExecutionListener {

    @Override
    public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        final String jobName = jobExecution.getJobInstance().getJobName();
        LOGGER.info("Listener to check one {} job instance is running", jobName);
        if (Constants.JOB_NAME.equals(jobName)) {
            final Set<JobExecution> executionSet = jobExplorer.findRunningJobExecutions(jobName);
            if (executionSet.size() > 1) {
                for (JobExecution execution : executionSet) {
                        execution.stop();
                        LOGGER.info("{} job instance {} is stopped", jobName, execution.getJobInstance().getInstanceId());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

to run the job:

```
 @Scheduled(cron = "0/10 * * * * *")
 public void runSpringBatchJob() {
     LOGGER.info("Job was started");
     final JobExecution streamExecution = jobLauncher.run(job, newExecution());
     LOGGER.info("Exit data job with status: {}", streamExecution.getStatus());
     LOGGER.info("Exit data job ID: {}", streamExecution.getJobId());
     LOGGER.info("-----------------------------------------------------");
}
```

LOG:

```
SpringBatchJobLauncher       : Job was started
SingleJobInstanceListener    : Listener to check one testJob job instance is running
SingleJobInstanceListener    : testJob job instance 178 is stopped
SingleJobInstanceListener    : testJob job instance 160 is stopped
SingleJobInstanceListener    : testJob job instance 154 is stopped
StreamWriter                 : Writing data: [......]
SpringBatchJobLauncher       : Exit data job with status: COMPLETED
SpringBatchJobLauncher       : Exit data job ID: 178
SpringBatchJobLauncher       : -----------------------------------------------------
SpringBatchJobLauncher       : Job was started
SingleJobInstanceListener    : Listener to check one testJob job instance is running
SingleJobInstanceListener    : testJob job instance 160 is stopped
SingleJobInstanceListener    : testJob job instance 179 is stopped
SingleJobInstanceListener    : testJob job instance 154 is stopped
StreamWriter                 : Writing data: [......]
SpringBatchJobLauncher       : Exit data job with status: COMPLETED
SpringBatchJobLauncher       : Exit data job ID: 179
```

so my question is what is the reason that makes the job instanced 3 times (because each time the job is running it's instanced 3 times), and if the job 178 is stoped why is it running again `Exit data job ID: 178`

Answer (score 0):

The feature you are trying to implement is already provided by Spring Batch, given that you correctly define a centralized transactional job repository and correctly design job instances with distinct identifying job parameters.

With this listener approach, you are running an additional job execution and checking if there is another one currently running. With Spring Batch's built-in feature, the second job execution is not even started, the job launcher will prevent that at startup time (this fail-fast approach is more efficient).

With locally scheduled jobs like you seem to have, a good identifying job parameter could be the run timestamp. For example, you will have a job instance every 10 minutes. Now if another scheduled method tries to run the same job instance say of 9:10 **at the same time** as the first method, then Spring Batch will prevent one of them from running, thanks to the centralized transactional job repository approach.

This also works in a clustered environment where another instance of your application (at the JVM level) tries to run the same job instance of 9:10 **at the same time** as the first application. Spring Batch will also prevent a duplicate job execution of the same instance. However, in a distributed environment where clock synchronization is not guaranteed, the single timestamp parameter won't be enough to identify job instances, you would need to add another discriminator to the identifying job parameters set in order to uniquely identify job instances at the cluster level.